# Сетевое соединение на Android

Tags: android, windows, сеть

Есть компьютер с Windows. На нем поднят TCP сервер. Нужно к этому серверу подключиться из Android-приложения. Вопрос - как организовать физический канал связи между компьютером и андроид-устройством (телефоном или планшетом)?

Доступа в Интернет нет. Беспроводные соединения крайне не желательны. Расстояние между андроидом и компьютером порядка 1-2 метров.

Comment: Воткнуться в USB и пробросить порт через adb?

Comment: @andreymal adb придется каждый раз запускать руками? Хотелось один раз все настроить для конкретной пары, а потом чтобы сетевое соединение поднималось автоматически без участия пользователя сразу после подключения кабеля

Comment: К сожалению не слышал о такой возможности

Comment: @andreymal тогда такой вопрос: допустим adb будет запускать некоторая служба, которая будет отслеживать подключение устройства. Но я все равно не понимаю как нужно его запускать? `adb connect` устанавливает соединение с TCP сервером на андроиде, но мне то нужно в обратную сторону, когда андроид будет клиентом. Может есть какие-то аппаратные решения? Типа EthernetToUsb?

Comment: @andreymal вот нашел такую статью https://ichip.ru/sovety/ekspluataciya/kak-podklyuchit-smartfon-na-android-k-domashnej-lan-seti-cherez-kabel-poshagovaya-instrukciya-711522

Comment: adb reverse позволяет пробросить порт сервера из компа в андроид

Comment: Кстати насчёт Ethernet — если подключить андроид в режиме USB-модема, то он определяется как сетевая карта, и оба устройства получают по динамическому IP-адресу, через которые можно подключаться. Правда, как выяснить IP-адреса обоих устройств кроме как ручным просмотром ifconfig, я не очень понял

Comment: не понятно в чём конкретно может появиться проблема, если, как уже было предложено, использовать RNDIS-интерфейс для прямого соединения ПК и Android-устройства (тоже самое можно сделать заведя в домашнюю беспроводную сеть). Данные технологии поддерживаются всем современными ОС (и даже WIndows 7/XP). Что мешает поднять терминального клиента на андроид-устройстве, а на ПК - SSH/Telnet-сервис, соответственно. Можно хоть netcat/FTP,SNMP - развернуть множество сервисов и, соотвеnственно, - клиентов на Андроид. Туда же можно воткнуть множество решений автоматизации:AutoDroid, AutomateIt, etc.